# Need help to understand and retrieve ansible dictionary from list in another dictionary

Tags: ansible

I do a debug from a lookup file (a dict):

```
   - Name: debugging
      debug:
        msg:"{{ linux_file_list | dict2items }}"
```

and I receive the following:

```
TASK [reposync : debugging] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "key": "list_of_linux",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "description": "linux SLES",
                        "enabled": 1,
                        "version": 15,
                        "name": "sles"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "linux RHEL",
                        "enabled": 1,
                        "version": 8.4,
                        "name": "rhel"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

First of all, I'd like to know what I think is correct:
It is a dict and the value of dict is two lists and each element of these lists are a dict. It is correct?
Second, I need to be able to iterate on each element to get the data for each linux type defined by 'name'. So something like that:

```
    "name: {{ item['name'] }}"
    "description: {{ item['description'] }}"
    "version: {{ item['version'] }}"
   loop: "{{ list_of_linux }}"
```

I don't know if my approach is right but I thought to create a dict and define name as a key, like that:

```
- set_fact:
    list_of_linux: "{{ dict(_keys(linux_file_list['value'])) }}"
  vars:
    _keys: "{{ item['value']|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
  loop: "{{ linux_file_list | dict2items }}"
```

But it doesn't run and I don't see how to manipulate these data...
Could someone help me to understand how to retrieve dict value from list

Here're additional information:

Here's my original file:

```
---
List_of_linux
  - name: sles
    description: "Linux SLES"
    enabled: 1
    version: 15
  - name: rhel
    description: "Linux RHEL"
    enabled: 1
    version: 8.4
  - …
```

This file is extern and I received it through a lookup and put it into a variable named : **linux_file_list**. This file becomes a dict. I've check that through type_debug and here's the simple output of variable, like: `msg: "{{ linux_file_list }}"`

Commands check:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ linux_file_list | type_debug }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ linux_file_list }}"
```

Results:

```
ok: [<server>]  => {
    "msg": ": dict"


ok: [<server>] => {
    "msg":  {'list_of_linux': [{'name': 'sles', 'description': 'Linux SLES', 'enabled': 1, 'version': 15}, {'name': 'rhel', 'description': 'Linux RHEL', 'enabled': 1, 'version': 8.4}]}"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help
H

Comment: could you show your original file linux_file_list?  without the modification dict2items

Comment: i have fixed my answer following the info you have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your starting structure:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    linux_file_list: "{{ lookup('file', './variables.yml') | from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug: 
        msg: | 
            description: {{ item.description }}
            name: {{ item.name }}
            version: {{ item.version }}
      loop: "{{ linux_file_list.List_of_linux }}"
```

**result:**

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'sles', 'description': 'Linux SLES', 'enabled': 1, 'version': 15}) => {
    "msg": "description: Linux SLES\nname: sles\nversion: 15\n"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'rhel', 'description': 'Linux RHEL', 'enabled': 1, 'version': 8.4}) => {
    "msg": "description: Linux RHEL\nname: rhel\nversion: 8.4\n"
}
```

Comment: Great! Now I receive exactly what I need. I didn't thing to parse the loop like that. Merci beaucoup @Frenchy

Comment: glad to help you, dont forget to validate/upvote my answer to close the question